# Will a ContextVar leak memory in async logic if not reset after Exception?

Tags: python, asynchronous, memory-leaks, python-internals, python-contextvars

If I have a structure in an async webserver like

```py
import contextvars
...
my_context_var = contextvars.ContextVar("var")

@app.route("/foo")  # decorator from webserver
async def some_web_endpoint():
    local_ctx_var = my_context_var.set(params.get("bar"))  # app sets params
    await some_function_that_can_raise()
    local_ctx_var.reset()
```

Will it leak memory if I don't wrap the `ContextVar` in a `finally:` block and `some_function_that_can_raise()` raises an Exception?
(without such a case, `.reset()` would never be called)

```py
    try:
        await some_function_that_can_raise()
    finally:
        local_ctx_var.reset()
```

.. or is it safe to assume the value will be destroyed when the request scope ends?
[The async example in the upstream docs doesn't actually bother `.reset()`-ing it at all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#asyncio-support)!
In such a case, `.reset()` is redundant as it happens right before the context is cleaned up anyways.

---

To add some more context (ha), I'm recently learning about ContextVars and I assume the second is the case.

`local_ctx_var` is the only name which refers to the Token ([from `.set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#contextvars.ContextVar.set)), and as the name is deleted when the request scope ends, the local value should become candidate for garbage collection, preventing a potential leak and making `.reset()` unnecessary for short-lived scopes (hooray)

..but I'm not absolutely certain, and while there's some very extremely helpful information on the subject, it muddles the mixture slightly

- [What happens if I don't reset Python's ContextVars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856654/what-happens-if-i-dont-reset-pythons-contextvars) (implies it'll be GC'd as one would expect)
- [Context variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854974/context-variables-in-python) (explicitly uses `finally:`)

Comment: I'm a little surprised `contextvars.Token` doesn't support the context manager protocol - I would have expected the standard idiom for this to be `with my_context_var.set(params.get("bar")): ...`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Me too - for example [loguru's `.contextualize`](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#loguru._logger.Logger.contextualize) makes use of `ContextVar`s in such a way! Maybe it would make a good PEP? ..though that it's not seems like a good indicator that any leftovers will eventually be cleaned up without `.reset()`

Answer (score 4):

Yes - the previous value of the context_var is kept in the token object in this case. There is this [rather similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856654/what-happens-if-i-dont-reset-pythons-contextvars/), where one of the answers run a simple benchmark to assert that calling `context_var.set()` multiple times and discarding the return value does not consume memory, when compared to, say, create a new string and keeping a reference to it.

Given the benchmark, I made some further experimentation and concluded there is no leak - in fact, in code like the above, calling `reset` is indeed redundant - it is useful if you'd have to restore the previous value inside a loop construct for some reason.

The new var is set, on *top* of the last saved context,  the value set in the current version of the context is simply discarded along the way: the only references to it are the one left in the tokens, if any.  In ohtther words: what preserves the previous values in a "stack like" way are calls to `contextvars.run` and `contextvars.copy_context` only, not `Contextvar.set`.

Comment: Excellent - this mostly confirms my suspicions, but also seems unfinished? I'll see if I can bring a good async test, which is what I'm really interested in beyond what's in that post, but I imagine it'll behave similarly (ContextVar becomes a candidate for GC after request finishes along with its other deleted names)

Comment: Great.
I have a personal project I started a little before contextvars was launched - I use another approach to keeping the contexts (I keep contextualized values in the execution frame locals vars) - it is not published, but the main class there `ContextLocals` works like a charm: https://github.com/jsbueno/extracontext/blob/master/tests/test_async.py - if you find that useful, do not hesitate to create issues so we can do a usable release.